# Is there any option to get the data in Formulas -> Name Manager in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing

I have to parse an excel using python, Used pandas for the same.

Is there any option to get the data in Formulas -> Name Manager in excel using python/pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `openpyxl`. It has the `defined_names`, to read from defined names in excel. see [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html)

Comment: wb = load_workbook(filename = "2900_Rules_Expression_1.xlsx") wb.defined_names.definedName. This will give the details of all defined names and definedNamesList[i].name will give the name and definedNamesList[i].attr_text will give the formulae of the defined names.

Answer (score 0):

wb = load_workbook(filename = "2900_Rules_Expression_1.xlsx") wb.defined_names.definedName. This will give the details of all defined names and definedNamesList[i].name will give the name and definedNamesList[i].attr_text will give the formulae of the defined names